# Geometrical constructions of numbers

Tags: geometry, number-theory, arithmetic, euclidean-geometry

There are many ways to construct numbers (as points) with straightedge and/or compass systematically.

> Consider a reference curve $\mathcal{C}$ (a straight line or a
> circle), a set of points $\mathcal{P}_0$ initially lying on it, and a
> rule $\mathcal{P}_{n+1}$ for constructing new points on it in the next
> step $n+1$.

The numbers of a given kind can then be constructed in an iterative process.

It might be interesting to see, how such a set of numbers relates to $ \mathcal{C}, \mathcal{P}_0, \mathcal{P}_{n+1}$ giving rise to it.

Let me name specific points as complex numbers (e.g. $0 = 0+i0$, $1 = 1 +i0$, $i = 0 +i1$, and so on). Let $\overline{XY}$ be the straight line through the points $X,Y$. Let $\bigcirc(X,Y)$ be the circle with center $X$ containing $Y$. Let $X \cap Y$ be the intersection point(s) of two curves $X,Y$. Let $||(X,Y)$ be the line parallel to the straight line  $X$ going through point $Y$ (not lying on $X$). Let $\times (X,Y)$ be the line perpendicular to the straight line $X$ going through $Y$ (not lying on $X$).

(For a better understanding, in the following the cases $\mathcal{P}_1$ and $\mathcal{P}_2$ are depicted.)

---

**Example 1 : $\mathbb{Z}$**

$\mathcal{C} =  \overline{01} $

$\mathcal{P}_0 = \{0, 1\} =: Z_{0}$

$\mathcal{P}_{n+1}= \{ \bigcirc (A,B) \cap\ \mathcal{C}\  |\  A,B \in \mathcal{P}_{n} \} =: Z_{n+1}$

[image]

$\lim_{n\rightarrow\infty} Z_n = \mathbb{Z}$

Let $iZ_{n}$ be the same for $\mathcal{C} = \overline{0i}$ and $\mathcal{P}_0 = \{0, i\}$ – needed for Example 3 : $\mathbb{Q}$.

---

**Example 2 : $\mathbb{Z}/6\mathbb{Z}$**

$\mathcal{C} =  \bigcirc (0,1) $

$\mathcal{P}_0 = \{1\}$

$\mathcal{P}_{n+1} = \{ \bigcirc (A,0) \cap  \mathcal{C}\  |\  A \in \mathcal{P}_{n} \} = \{ \bigcirc (A,B) \cap  \mathcal{C}\  |\  A,B \in \mathcal{P}_{n} \}$

[image]

$\mathcal{P}_{3} = \mathbb{Z}/6\mathbb{Z}$

---

**Example 3 : $\mathbb{Q}$**

$\mathcal{C} =  \overline{01} $

$\mathcal{P}_0 = \{0, 1\} =: Q_0$

$\mathcal{P}_{n+1}= Z_{n+1} \cup \{ ||(\overline{AB},i) \cap \mathcal{C}\  |\  A \in Z_{n+1} , B \in iZ_{n+1} \} =: Q_{n+1}$

[image]

$\lim_{n\rightarrow\infty} Q_n = \mathbb{Q}$

---

**Example 4 : $\mathbb{Q}^\sqrt{}$** (the [constructible numbers](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Constructible_number))

$\mathcal{C} =  \overline{01} $

$\mathcal{P}_0 = \{0, 1\} $

$\mathcal{P}_{n+1}= Q_{n+1} \cup \{ \bigcirc \big(0,\bigcirc (A,\text{-} 1) \cap \overline{0i}\ \big) \cap \mathcal{C}\  |\  A \in Q_{n+1}  \} $

[image]

$\lim_{n\rightarrow\infty} \mathcal{P}_n = \mathbb{Q}^\sqrt{}$

---

My questions are:

> 1. Do the above statements hold (concerning limits $\lim_{n\rightarrow \infty} X_n = \mathbb{X}$)?
> 2. Of what mathematical or didactical interest might this approach and its visualization be? What can be learned from it?

One thing, that really astonishes me: After each step all "intermediate" curves (straight lines and circles) are "thrown away" – and there are really many of them:

[image] <sub>[[source](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2911971/covering-the-euclidean-plane-with-constructible-lines-and-circles)]</sub>

Only the reference lines and the constructed points lying on them are supposed to remain after each step.

> How can it be proved, that **no distance between any two intersection
> points of all these intermediate curves** will – in the limit
> – be different from all the "officially" constructed points'
> distances from the origin $O$?