# A geometrical analogy between $1/x$ and $\sqrt{x}$

Tags: arithmetic, euclidean-geometry

In a question on [geometrical constructions of numbers](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2922954/geometrical-constructions-of-numbers), two constructions appear to be related by analogy.

In the first construction a specific **straight line** $L$ (blue) is constructed (going through $1$ and $ix $). The line $L'$ which is parallel to $L$ and goes through the point $i$ (red) yields the number $1/x$:

[image]

In the second construction a specific **circle** $C$ (blue) is constructed (going through $-1$ and $x$). The circle $C'$ with center $0$ and going through the intersection $i\sqrt{x}$ of $C$ with the straight line $\overline{0i}$ yields the number $\sqrt{x}$:

[image]

I wonder which arithmetic meaning might be given to this analogy of constructions, i.e. what might an analogy between $1/x$ and $\sqrt{x}$ be in arithmetic terms?

> What do the arithmetic operations $1/x$ and $\sqrt{x}$ have in
> common – in arithmetic terms? Which single concept are they examples of?

---

(In arithmetic terms $\sqrt{x}$ is the inverse of $x^2$, i.e. $\sqrt{x^2} = \sqrt{x}^2 =  x$. For $1/x$ we find $x^2/x = x$, but this doesn't make $1/x$ an inverse of $x^2$, because $(1/x)^2 \neq x$.)

Comment: "which somehow is "parallel" to it": no, these circles are in general position. Seeing parallelism there is abuse.

Comment: Not really: Their relative positions are closely related. At least they will always intersect each other (as long as $x$ is on the right side).

Comment: Maybe talking of "parallelism" was a bad idea. It's only because the pair of circles plays a similar role as the pair of (parallel) lines.

Comment: The are secant, full stop. (Which by the way, is not the first-class property of parallel entities.)

Comment: Please allow me to drop the mention of "parallel circles", it's not essential for my question. (Sorry for making your comments obsolete.)

Comment: Maybe with some suitable geometric inversion (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Inversive_geometry) you can show that the two figures are in fact a single one.

Comment: No, thank you .

Comment: Here's an alternative way to link $1/x$ and $\sqrt{x}$ with a construction. Consider $\triangle ABC$ with right angle at $A$, and drop a perpendicular from $A$ to point $D$ on $\overline{BC}$. With $|BD| = x$, we have the following: (1) If $|AD|=1$, then $|CD|=1/x$, and (2) if $|CD|=1$, then $|AD| = \sqrt{x}$.

Comment: Beautiful! And helpful. Thanks. (Should it be immediately clear how this finding relates to my question?)

Comment: @HansStricker: It's just something that came to mind. It doesn't address your question, *per se*, although seeing the $1/x$ and $\sqrt{x}$ as counterparts of the same construction might give you more food for thought.

Comment: @Blue Your comment actually applies more or less directly to both of the given examples, although in the first case we would need to rotate the red line a quarter turn clockwise to construct your triangle. In the second case $A=i\sqrt x,$ $B=x,$ $C=-1,$ and $D=0.$ It's all about similar right triangles in both cases.